# Plain Data Bean, Caller of Autowired Bean (a @Component), Sees NULL

Tags: spring

Newbie Spring question. I have a @Component class, correctly annotated, which brings me my environment configuration.

```
@Component
public class EnvConfig { 
   //...
}
```

Because it's a @Component it gets picked up by auto-injection.

But the caller of this class is a plain data bean. The plain data bean has a special utility method that needs to access this class.

```
public class EmployeeBean {

   @Autowired
   EnvConfig envConfig;

   //...

   public void getSpecialInfo() 
   {
       envConfig.method1();
       envConfig.method2();
   }
}
```

envConfig is **NULL** when I debug into this method.

So the caller of Autowired objects **also** needs to be a @Component, @Service, or @Repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More or less, yes. Spring can obviously just autowire objects that it manages (in other words, "Spring Beans") - how could it do otherwise? So, if you create an object yourself (`new ...`), then it's not a "spring bean", just a random object and Spring has no control over it - and it also cannot autowire something there automatically.

One way of doing so is making them `@Component`, etc. and let them be found via Spring's component scanning.

Other ways to create Spring beans would be JavaConfig (via `@Bean`), XML config (via `<bean .../>`) and others (for example via PreProcessors, but that starts getting esoteric).

Of course, you could also use some static access to the Spring's application context to let your own objects access spring beans - but that's not a really good way.

Comment: Remember to place annotated classes in package which is defined through `@ComponentScan`  / `<context:component-scan>`

Comment: Alternatively, one can use the power of Spring Boot and not care too much about that stuff ;-)

Comment: But one should be aware about limitations :) AFAIK `@SpringBootApplication` uses `@ComponentScan` without `basePackage` parameter. So, one can place `Application` in "wrong" place (e.g. nested package) and it may not magically work on whole app (root) package ;)

Comment: True, this is why I wrote "too much". A little bit of thinking is always good ;-)